# Advice on a purchase of a touchscreen display from adafruit for raspberry pi

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, hardware, raspberry-pi2

Advice on a purchase of a touchscreen display from adafruit for raspberry pi needed . Does video scaling matter? What is video scaling for? I will be using the raspberry Pi to run a digital signage project for my shop which will be displaying graphical text and maybe a short video clip.

http://www.adafruit.com/products/2407 
This particular product number (product 2407) does not contain a video scaler, it will not resize/shrink video! (What does it mean by it will not resize or shrink video? does it mean that if i were to use my raspberry pi to play a video the video would not resize or is there more to it? )

http://www.adafruit.com/products/2395
This product seems bulkier but has no mention of display scaling issue otherwise.

Please do help and advice. Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a hardware purchase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this question

http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=75443&p=382536&hilit=video+scaler#p382536

" Not having the scalar means you might have to configure the system for the exact screen size (800x480) and it may be an issue in showing movies. "

Credits to : michaelmeissner

Comment: You asked a completely off-topic question, and then you posted an equally off-topic answer.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I think you need to re read again what i post i wasn't sure i need a video scaler or not. and the link i posted clarifies my question which no one on this forum was able to help. Sorry if you think my english isn't understandable but you don't have to be so rude.